# Is it possible to change "sender email" in sendEmail?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am currently working on a script that sends email to the user if the excel has been updated. I am able to send the email. However, when testing, I notice  that the "sender" email is my email. I would like to change the "sender" email to another email ("companyemail@gmail.com"). How can I achieve it if possible? I would like to do this as it will be a google add-on (as in you will be able to install the addon on Google Forms, Spreadsheet, etc.). If it can not be done using MailApp or GmailApp, what is an alternative?

```
 function sendEmail(e){
  var email = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("email.html");
  var htmlText = email.evaluate().getContent();

  Logger.log(htmlText);

  var emailTo = e.response.getRespondentEmail();
  //var emailFrom = 'companyemail@gmail.com'

  var subject = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
  var textBody = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";
  var options = { htmlBody: htmlText };

  if(emailTo !== undefined){
   GmailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, subject, textBody, options);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an [alias](https://www.alphr.com/how-to-create-a-gmail-alias/) first to do that. Complete the steps on the link.

Once an alias is created, confirm if it is being returned when calling `GmailApp.getAliases()`

Upon confirmation, you can now use it on the `from` parameter under advanced parameters.

> the address that the email should be sent from, which must be one of the values returned by getAliases()

#### Reference:

- [GmailApp Advanced Parameters](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#advanced-parameters_1)

Comment: :Thank you for your help and will read the steps. I do have a question: once the add-on is published in the google store, will the alias still be directed to the email?

Comment: I don't think it would be possible as an add-on. The idea is other people doesn't have access with your alias so it won't be possible. But if you add the same alias to the people that will use your add-on, then it may be possible but I'm not sure if that's the best way to do that. If you are in the same company, then maybe. If you are not and you are sharing the add on to random people you don't know, I don't think that's good.

Comment: I see. I would want strangers(clients) to have access to this add-on and to be notified when excel(database) has been updated

Comment: I was hoping if there was a way to manually enter the sender email. Is that possible?

Comment: Sadly, it wouldn't be possible. If the user doesn't have a confirmed access with the said email, then it wouldn't be possible to use it as alias.

Comment: @RobertoFlores, if this answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon).  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)